# What does "sex out of marriage" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, expressions

What does it mean when we say "**sex outside marriage**" or sex out of marriage? Is it same as *sex before marriage* (ie. **premarital** sex), or does it include *having sex with someone while being married to someone else* (ie. **extramarital** sex).

The source of this doubt is a video, which states that it is a woman's choice whether she wishes to have sex **before** marriage or have sex **out of** marriage.

Here's the transcript: [**My Choice**](http://tribune.com.pk/story/860808/my-body-my-mind-my-choice-deepika-padukone/) by Deepika Padukon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it means the same thing. When you are married, you are *in* a legal union, and in many cultures and religions you are permitted to have physical relations, *within* those parameters. If you are not married, you are *outside of* or *out of* those parameters.

The added meaning of *out of* compared to before is that it could take place after a divorce, or with somebody else you are not married to, even while married. Basically, it is with anyone you are not married to.